# Selecting bootstrap drop down with jquery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a `twitter-bootstrap select` that I am trying to iterate with jquery to build a list of `google-maps` markers(latitude/longitude/building-id is stored with list). on document ready I want to iterate the list and extract the lat/long from each li item and create a marker with that location:

```
        <select id="buildings" class="selectpicker" data-width="100%" data-live-search="true"><!-- style="border-radius:0px;" -->
            {% for category in buildings %}
                <optgroup label="{{ category.category.asBuildingCategory }}">
                    {% for building in category.buildings %}
                        <option data-content="<span data-latitude='{{building.fLatitude}}' data-longitude='{{building.fLongitude}}' data-build-id='{{building.ixBuilding}}'>{{building.asBuildingName}}</span>"></option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </optgroup>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
```

This is what the code generated looks like in the browser:
[image]

I can successfully attach an onclick for each menu item, but I can't seem to iterate the `select` list via jquery.

Thus far I have tried this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".dropdown-menu.inner.selectpicker li").each(function () {
        alert($(this));
    });
});
```

but it doesn't seem to hit anything. However This code works for adding the click listener:

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.dropdown-menu.inner.selectpicker li', function () {
    debugger;
    var latitude = $(this).find("span").data('latitude');
    var longitude = $(this).find("span").data('longitude');
    var buildingID = $(this).find("span").data('build-id');
});
```

**EDIT**
This is what my jquery finds using this code:
[image]

```
var test = $(".dropdown-menu.inner.selectpicker li");
```

It just gets the entire document instead of the list elements

Comment: aren't you just missing dots? ".dropdown-menu.inner.selectpicker li" instead of "dropdown-menu inner selectpicker li"

Comment: I had dots before and still didn't work(forgot to re-add them back in when mucking around)

Comment: I just tried the exact same code and it's working fine. Any errors on console (dev tools)? Well, I guess you checked the console out already...

Comment: I have checked but there isn't anything. I'm wondering then if it's by any chance just my visual studio going whack, I've noticed in the past few days some funky stuff happening where I wouldn't change anything and something would break but when I come back 5 minutes later it suddenly works again

Comment: :D Have you tried running the jquery code via the console? That's how i just tested it

Comment: @john Same here. I just tested it as well and it's working fine :).

Comment: well then I'll just try and restart VS tomorrow when I get back, murphie's law.. I'll post back if it fixed it

Comment: re-tested it and it still doesn't work. I'll post a picture of what the selector finds.

Answer (score 0):

Your markup doesn't add up. It looks like something mutates your markup on the browser for your select to have the classes `.dropdown-menu.inner.selectpicker` since your markup before it hits the browser only shows class `selectpicker`:

```
    <select id="buildings" class="selectpicker" ...>
```

Use the ID instead if you have multiple `selectpicker` classes:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#buildings li").each(function () {
        alert($(this));
    });
});
```

Comment: That's all thanks to `twitter-bootstrap`. You build a list then bootstrap takes it and constructs a custom `select` with all types of css added. The reason I can't iterate the original list is because `twitter-boostrap` adds a `display: none;`

Comment: Yeah I figured that after I re-read the title, but I'd already posted this answer

Comment: yeah, still appreciate the answer though. Just can't wrap my head around why this isn't working.

Comment: This still won't work if this javascript is included before your bootstrap js

Comment: won't `$(document).ready` prevent this or is there a way to make sure my js is included after `bootstrap` js

Comment: You could also just target the data source: make your jQuery selector `#buildings optgroup option`, that's guaranteed to be there when your JavaScript loads